# Postback JSON passing data to ViewBag MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, model-view-controller

```
 @Html.DropDownList("GroupCode",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.GroupCode,"-- Please Select --", new{@id="groupcd"})
```

DropDownList to select group and post back the value selected to JSON to get a list of clientcode and put into another DropDownList

```
$(function() {
    $("#groupcd").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $("#groupcd").val();
        $.post('@Url.Action("getClientCD", "OutstandingClaim")', { selection: selectedValue }, function (data) {
            $("#clientcd").html(data);

        });
    });
});
```

Javascript to get the selected value and post to action

```
        public JsonResult getClientCD(string selection)
    {
        var data = db.Common_CustMas.Where(c => c.Group == selection)
                .ToList().Select(x => string.Format("{0}--{1}", x.CUSTCODE, x.CUSTNAME));
        ViewBag.ClientCode = data;
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

after post back to controller, query the list out and pass back

```
@Html.DropDownList("ClientCD", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.ClientCode, "--Please Select --", new{@id="clientcd"})
```

The query works, but no data was passed back to the ViewBag client code. Anyone know what problem and how to solve this?

Comment: ViewBag comes into the picture only at the time of rendering View

in this case u r not rendering view instead returning some list items which should be a json result

Comment: o i  c, so how to pass back the json result to the dropdownlist, do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do  this way

```
$('#CityID').change(function () {
            var cityid = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("PopulateDistrictsList ","Controller")',
                data: { CityID: cityid },
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                   var ddldist = $('#DistrictID');
                    $.each(data, function (val, text) {
                        ddldist.append(
                            $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
                        );
                    });

                },
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

finally it solved with the code

```
$(function() {
     $("#groupcd").change(function () {
         var selectedValue = $("#groupcd").val();
         $.getJSON('@Url.Action("getClientCD", "OutstandingClaim")', { selection: selectedValue }, function (result) {
             var ddl = $('#clientcd');
             ddl.empty();
             $(result).each(function () {
                 ddl.append(
                     $('<option/>').html(this.Text)
                 );
             });
         });
     });
});
```

controller

```
public JsonResult getClientCD(string selection)
    {
        var data = (from a in db.Common_CustMas
                                  where a.Group == selection
                                  select new {Text = ( a.CUSTCODE + "-" + a.CUSTNAME)}).Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownList("GroupCode",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.GroupCode,"-- Please Select --", new{@id="groupcd"})

 @Html.DropDownList("ClientCD", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()),new{@id="clientcd"})
```